# How can DynamoDB be HA and eventually consistent at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, high-availability, eventual-consistency

I'm reading up on [AWS DynamoDB's versioning best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html) and not understanding something:

How can DynamoDB be HA **and** eventually consistent at the same time?!

My *understanding* of the setup is to:

1. Maintain (at least) a `version` column in your data
2. When you insert a new record, insert it as version 0 ("v0")
3. Every time you want to make a change to that record, you insert a new (incremented) version and then apply the same changes to v0 as well
4. All reads are against v0 (the most current, up to date version)

However I'm not understanding how DynamoDB can enforce update conditions when its billed as an eventually consistent DB! Has anyone ever had experience implementing these guidelines/practices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDB is not just "eventually consistent", it actually has a notion of strong consistency, [described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html):

> When you request a strongly consistent read, DynamoDB returns a response with the most up-to-date data, reflecting the updates from all prior write operations that were successful.

Moreover, when an update also involves a read - due to an `UpdateExpresion` or `ConditionExpression` - this read is also, always, done in a strongly-consistent matter.

But it's more than that... Just strongly-consistent reads will not help you to allow concurrent updates to the versions. What you need is to use a technique such as **optimistic locking** to allow concurrent writes of a new version:

1. Read (`GetItem`) the current value of the item (in v0). Eventually consistent is fine.
2. In this item we find the current version number, say 7.
3. Write (`UpdateItem`) a new value for v0 with the version number 8 (one past the 7 we read), **with the ConditionExpression that version = 7**. If this condition fails (`ConditionalCheckFailedException`), goto 1.
4. If the condition succeeded, this client was successful in setting version 8, and will be the **only** client that succeeded to set version 8. So we send another `UpdateItem` and set the separate v8 item.

This technique has a risk that the client may die between steps 3 and 4, and the entry for v8 will be missing, although the entry in v0 will be new. But this is always the risk when you try to set the same data in two different items - one write may succeed and the other will fail - and the only way around this issue is to use the new DynamoDB feature of [transactions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/).

Answer (score 0):

While there's some great info in the other answer, I don't think it quite answers your question of

> How can DynamoDB be HA and eventually consistent at the same time?

The answer is simple, DDB partitions are 3 way replicated...
[image: from AWS reInvent DDB deep dive]

If you have watch the [AWS Dynamo Deep Dive video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k), I highly recommend it.

So when you write to DDB, it passes the write along to all three replica's and returns success to you after 2 of the three write succeeds.

An eventually consistent read to DDB also passes the read to all three replicas and returns to the caller the first response it gets.

So it's possible that a write could succeed to two replicas, and still be pending on another; and that an eventually consistent read returns the data from the out of date replica.

Obviously, having three replicas gives you the high availability.

Comment: > So when you write to DDB, it passes the write along to all three replica's and returns success to you **any of the three write succeeds**.

This is not true according to this [video](https://youtu.be/yvBR71D0nAQ?t=298). It requires two acknowledgements from the storage node.

Comment: @jellycsc thanks for the correction, will update my answer